# How to use a subquery as table name?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have two Posts-tables, plus a Middleman-table which detect one of those Posts-tables.

```
// Post1                                // Post2
+----+--------+--------------+           +----+--------+--------------+
| id | title  |   content    |           | id | title  |   content    |
+----+--------+--------------+           +----+--------+--------------+
| 1  | how    | are you?     |           | 1  | nice   | to meet you  |
+----+--------+--------------+           +----+--------+--------------+


// Middleman
+------------+------------+
| table_code | table_name |
+------------+------------+
| 100        | Post1      |
| 101        | Post2      |
+------------+------------+
```

Also I have a Votes table like this:

```
+----+---------+------------+---------+-------+-----------+
| id | post_id | table_code | user_id | value | timestamp |
+----+---------+------------+---------+-------+-----------+
| 1  | 1       | 101        | xxx     | -1    | xxx       |
+----+---------+------------+---------+-------+-----------+
```

Now I want to get `title`(*nice*) and `content`(*to meet you*) of that post which got a vote. Actually what I want is using of `Middleman`-table as a array (to give `table_code` and get `table_name`) and then use of that `table_name` to select considered post.

In other word, I have two parameters: `$post_id = 1`, `$table_code = 101`. Now I want to select first post in the `Post2` table (`Post2` is according to `101`). Something like this:

```
select title, content
   from 
     (select table_name
        from Middleman 
        where table_code = 101)
   where id = 1;
```

But it ^ doesn't work, How can I fix it?

**Note:** According to personal reasons, I don't want to use an PHP array instead of that `Middleman` table.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is possible or not, usually we find solutions by reorganizing the schema. Firstly, do we need the two tables : post1 and post2 both having essentially the same schema? If we could just have one table Post with id, title, content and get rid of the Middleman table, we may have solved the problem. The Votes table will have all the columns except for the table_code. Then you would easily query by doing:

```
select p.title, p.content from Post p join Votes v on p.id = v.post_id where v.post_id = 1;
```

Comment: `... from Post ... `. That  `Post` is which one?

Comment: `create table Post(id int, title varchar(100), content varchar(400))` , basically instead of Post1 and Post2, you just have one table called Post.

Comment: Ah, but actually I cannot to create one single table instead of those tow Posts table.

Comment: I am not sure why you cannot create one single table, but this would probably be a denormalized database schema: you will have to add a column in each post1 and post2 tables called "code" . With that you can do the following query: `select p1.* , p2.* from post1 p1, post2 p2 join votes v on v.table_code = p1.code OR v.table_code = p2.code `

Comment: I just edited my comment, still not a perfect solution

Comment: Just one question, Are these exactly the same? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3739e5ef726c85a1f0e8

Comment: No, they are not the same. The first query ` SELECT col1 FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT col1 FROM table2` returns one column with the values of col1 from both table1 and table2 one beneath the other where as the second query ` SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2 FRM table1 t1, table2 t2` would result in two column rows as result which is a cartesian product of table1 and table2